# Javascript mutates ABI objects

Tags: web3js, javascript, abi

I'm trying to import a contract ABI to my app but when I try to import it using `import` or `require` method, JavaScript mutates objects. Please check out this screenshots

This is normal ABI log in the console. I put ABI directly inside cosole.log() method

[image]

This is imported ABI from another file. As you can see some props added by JavaScript

[image]

Edit: more info about my setup

```
// ABI.json file which contains Pancakeswap ABI. copied from https://bscscan.com/address/0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e#code
// Web3.js linked with script tag in index.html
// I'm using Webpack to bundle modules


import contractABI from './ABI.json';
// Tried this too -> const contractABI = require('./ABI.json');
console.log(contractABI);
```

Comment: this is probably web3.js adding that for it's convenience. javascript has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Checked it again after removing Web3.js from project and now It's fixed! But I need Web3.js in my project. How can I stop Web3 from mutating ABI objects?

Comment: usually u import the abi through web3.js and use it with web3.js method calling. if u need the abi as it is, just read the file directly using fs on nodeJs or importing it from a json file.

Comment: Yes I need it as it is. Imported if from a .json file using "require" method but still Web3 mutates it.

Comment: Please post a snippet of your code to further explain your question.

Comment: Added more info to the post